# Disable incremental build in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, linker

I'm looking to disable incremental build in visual studio on a project I have. It is a WPF C# project. I would like the incremental build turned off so that the binaries will work with Mono.

I looked everywhere and for hours. All the answers are for c++ which has linker in the project properties section.

For my wpf project, there is no such settings. I  know I'm missing it somewhere and stackoverflow has the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Mono doesn't support WPF - do they? http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/wpf/

Comment: "Incremental build" is a C++ build feature, it has no meaning in C#.  The C# compiler always build an entire C# project from scratch and rewrites the executable file completely.  Why your binaries don't work with Mono is impossible to guess, but it certainly cannot support WPF.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will port my program to windows form. Thanks